# How can I access the contents of a form submission via Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have server side caching running on a website, and need to trigger functionality based on the submission of a form.  How can I access the contents of a form submission via Javascript?  Usually I would access these with PHP via $_POST.

I can't get the values via PHP because the page that is being served after the form submission is the cached page, and no PHP will be executed.

I am using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` is a server side PHP variable and has nothing do to with JavaScript.

Now the `$_POST` variable usually contains some kind of values submitted by a form, which **is** accessible by JavaScript. You can loop over the form and get the filled in values very easily.

#### code sample

If you are using jQuery you can get the values like this:

```
$("#myform input[name=first_name]").val();
```

Comment: Thank you.  I updated the question appropriately.  How can I access the contents of a form submission via Javascript?  Perhaps one cannot.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  alert($(this).serialize());
  return false;
});
```

You can do the above if you are using jQuery,

You could also do:

```
var form = document.getElementById("<yourformid>");
for(var i =0; i < form.elements.length; i++){
   // grab form.elements[i]
}
```